# Internal server error when trying to access the show view in Grails with a RestfulController

Tags: java, grails, groovy, crud, grails3

I'm building a simple Grails 3 web app supposed to work with Oracle 12c database. I have some tables without an explicit ID column so I have to use composite key and thus, also write my own controllers cause scaffolding doesn't work then. Here's an example domain class that I'd like to handle:

```
class AliasFrequencyDict implements Serializable{
    String frequency
    String unit
    String description
    String lang

    static constraints = {
        frequency maxSize: 10, sqlType: 'VARCHAR2'
        unit maxSize: 1, sqlType: 'VARCHAR2'
        description maxSize: 30, sqlType: 'VARCHAR2'
        lang maxSize: 2, sqlType: 'VARCHAR2'
    }

    static mapping = {
        sort 'frequency'
        version false
        id composite: ['frequency', 'unit', 'lang']
    }

    Map<String, String> getPK()
    {
        ['frequency': frequency, 'unit': unit, 'lang': lang]
    }
}
```

And while the list view works alright when I specify the properties in the `index.gsp`'s collection `properties`, I'd like to have all the CRUD actions work as well. Since rewriting everything from the default [scaffolding template](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/scaffolding/blob/master/src/main/templates/scaffolding/Controller.groovy#L56) sounded really daunting to me, being a newbie at Grails, I decided to try and do it with a [Restful Controller](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.x/guide/REST.html#extendingRestfulController), as it looks like it would need less code and explicit logic. Here's my controller code:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class AliasFrequencyDictController {
    def index(String frequency, String unit, String description, String lang) {
        params.frequency = frequency
        params.unit = unit
        params.description = description
        params.lang = lang

        respond AliasFrequencyDict.list(params), model:[aliasFrequencyDictCount: AliasFrequencyDict.count()]
    }

    def show(String frequency, String unit, String language) {

        def aliasFrequencyDict = AliasFrequencyDict.list() /*AliasFrequencyDict.get( new AliasFrequencyDict(params) )*/

        if(aliasFrequencyDict == null) {
            render status:404
        }
        else {
            return [aliasFrequencyDict: aliasFrequencyDict]
        }
    }
}
```

...and yet, when I try to access, say, `http://localhost:8080/aliasFrequencyDict/show?frequency=0&unit=Q&lang=EN`, I get:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI:/aliasFrequencyDict/show
Class:javax.servlet.ServletException
Message:Could not resolve view with name 'show' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

Why is that so? How should I approach fixing this?

EDIT: OK, the furthest I've been able to progress with this is manually adding a `show.gsp` in `aliasFrequencyDict`'s view folder but this only changes the error, not solves it. So now it is:

```
URI:/aliasFrequencyDict/show
Class:org.grails.taglib.GrailsTagException
Message:Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.Runtime
Exception: Error initializing GroovyPageViewCaused by:[grails-app\views\aliasFrequencyDict\show.gsp:23] Unclosed GSP expression
```

...and `show.gsp:23` is `<g:form resource="\${this.${propertyName}}" method="DELETE">` which has its `</g:form>` three lines down so, well, hardly unclosed :(